# How to redirect to certain pages depending on what option that I select for dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, forms, redirect, web, drop-down-menu

I have this table called FACILITIES. I already code it so that when for etc when meeting is selected for first dropdownlist, second dropdownlist will display the FAC_CODE column data that belongs to the FAC_TYPE column data.

The problem is whatever option that i choose for the FAC_CODE which belongs to any FAC_TYPE, it will always redirect to number1.aspx. I wan to make it  so that, if I choose Meeting for the FAC_TYPE and whatever option for the FAC_CODE it will go to number1.aspx. If I choose Tutorial for the FAC_TYPE and whatever option for the FAC_CODE it will go to number2.aspx. If I choose Lecture for the FAC_TYPE and whatever option for the FAC_CODE it will go to number2.aspx.

My first dropdownlist name which is the FAC_TYPE field is called ddlFacilityType and my second dropdownlist name which is the FAC_CODE field is called ddlFacility. Both have autopostback ticked. So how to code in the ddlFacility_SelectedIndexChanged event? bumps up for this thread

[image]
[image]
 [image]
[image]
[image]

```
public partial class MainMenu : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["projectConnectionString"].ToString(); // connection string
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();


            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select distinct FAC_TYPE from FACILITIES", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);  // fill dataset

            ddlFacilityType.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["FAC_TYPE"].ToString(); // text field name of table dispalyed in dropdown
            // to retrive specific  textfield name 
            ddlFacilityType.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];      //assigning datasource to the dropdownlist
            ddlFacilityType.DataBind();  //binding dropdownlist

            ddlFacilityType.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" Select type", "0"));
        }

        ddlFacility.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" Select room", "0"));
    }


    protected void ddlFacilityType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["projectConnectionString"].ToString(); // connection string
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();


        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select distinct FAC_CODE from FACILITIES where FAC_TYPE='" + ddlFacilityType.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);  // fill dataset

        ddlFacility.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["FAC_CODE"].ToString(); // text field name of table dispalyed in dropdown
        // to retrive specific  textfield name 
        ddlFacility.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];      //assigning datasource to the dropdownlist
        ddlFacility.DataBind();  //binding dropdownlist

        ddlFacility.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" Select room", "0"));
    }

    protected void ddlFacility_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("number1.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in on ddlFacility_SelectedIndexChanged handler.

```
protected void ddlFacility_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ddlFacilityType.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Meeting")
    {
        Response.Redirect("number1.aspx");
    }
    else if(ddlFacilityType.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Tutorial" || ddlFacilityType.SelectedItem.ToString()=="Lecture")
    {
        Response.Redirect("number2.aspx");
    }
}
```

You can also do the same thing by the SelectedIndex property of the dropdownlist, in that case, the code would be something like

```
if(ddlFacilityType.SelectedIndex == 1) //Meeting is at index 1 of the ddlFacilityType dropdown
{
    Response.Redirect("number1.aspx");
}
```